# 'Contains' dose not works with string?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am using dynamic linq to parse some conditions. I wrote stored procedure and want to filter it dynamicly.

this is my procedure:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,[NO]
        ,Firstname
        ,Lastname
        ,PersonalNO
        ,ReferanceID
        ,CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))  AS ReferanceNO
    FROM dbo.Employees WHERE ReferanceID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c.ID
        ,c.[NO]
        ,c.Firstname
        ,c.Lastname
        ,c.PersonalNO
        ,c.ReferanceID
        ,CASE
            WHEN ct.ReferanceNO = ''
                THEN CAST(ct.[NO] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                ELSE CAST(ct.[NO] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            END
    FROM dbo.Employees c
        INNER JOIN cte ct ON ct.ID = c.ReferanceID
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

and in C# I am calling this procedure;

```
public List<Employees> GetEmployees(string searchValue, int skip, int pageSize, string sortColumn, string sortColumnDir)
{
var query = DB.sp_GetConsultants().ToList();
var totalRecords = query.Count;

query = query.Where(searchValue).ToList(); // if the searchValue is value
 //"PersonalNO.Contains(\"15\")" it filters, with this kind of value
 //"Lastname.Contains(\"fish\")" it dose not, but with "Fish" it does. Is the matter with uppercase?
}
```

and i  uploaded table picture:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you print out (or enumerate using the debugger) the contents of the entire `query` list? Perhaps something is wrong with your stored procedure and it's not even including John Fisher?

Comment: I apologize, I reedited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.Contains` is case sensitive; as you noticed, searching for "fish" won't return "Fisher", even though searching for "Fish" will. There doesn't seem to be a case insensitive version in .NET (even though you can compare strings case insensitively as an option).

As a workaround, you can convert both strings to lowercase or uppercase (`ToLower` / `ToUpper`) before comparing. This might have some issues with certain non-Latin characters, however.

I think there is also a collation option in SQL Server which lets you specify the case sensitivity for strings, if you want to do the comparison at the database level instead.

Comment: I want to make the information more exact. In this case string.Contains is case sensitive because of I added .ToList() at the end of procedure.If I rewrite this query: var query = DB.sp_GetConsultants().AsQueryabla() case sensitive dose not matter. Right am I? and If I am, why?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with LINQ to SQL, but I imagine AsQueryable() does the search in the database; perhaps the database collation is set to case insensitive?